# How to import parquet data from S3 into HDFS using Sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, parquet, sqoop

I am trying to import data into a table in RDS. The data is in parquet file format and is present in s3.
I thought of importing the data from `s3` into HDFS using `Sqoop` and then exporting it into RDS table using Sqoop. I was able to find the command to export data from HDFS to RDS. But I couldn’t find for importing parquet data from S3. Could you please help on how to structure the `sqoop import` command in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that seemed simple and best for me is as below:

- Create a Parquet table  in Hive and load it with the Parquet data from S3

```
create external table if not exists parquet_table(<column name> <column's datatype>) stored as parquet;

LOAD DATA INPATH 's3a://<bucket_name>/<parquet_file>' INTO table parquet_table
```

- Create a CSV table in Hive and load it with the data from Parquet table

```
create external table if not exists csv_table(<column name> <column's datatype>)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location 'hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/csvdata'
```

- Now that we have a CSV/Textfile Table in Hive, Sqoop can easily export the table from HDFS to MySQL table RDS.

```
export --table <mysql_table_name> --export-dir hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/csvdata --connect jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/<db_name> --username <username> --password-file hdfs:///user/test/mysql.password --batch -m 1 --input-null-string "\\N" --input-null-non-string "\\N" --columns <column names to be exported, without whitespace in between the column names>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [spark](https://spark.apache.org/) to copy data from s3 to HDFS.

Read [this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-text-file-from-s3/) blog for more details.