# Can I use mysql database as destination storage for apache hudi

Tags: mysql, apache-hudi

I am new to Apache Hudi,Please let me know if there any configuration is provided in apache hudi for writing data on mysql database.

Comment: do you want to read a hudi table and write its data to mysql db?

Comment: yes , I am looking for configuration in hudi for writing data  on mysql just like spark, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552161/write-dataframe-to-mysql-table-using-pyspark/46556308#46556308 , If there is configuration options are present , Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write data from an Hudi table to MySQL, when you read your Hudi table as a dataframe, you can use spark `jdbc` driver to write the data to MySQL:

```py
# read hudi table
df = spark.read.format("hudi").load("/path/to/table")

# write dataframe to MySQL
df.write.format('jdbc').options(
      url='jdbc:mysql://<MySQL server url>/<database name>',
      driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
      dbtable='<table name>',
      user='<user name>',
      password='<password>'
).mode('append').save()
```

But if you want to use MySQL as a file system for your Hudi tables, the answer is no. Hudi manages the storage layer of the datasets on HCFS (Hadoop Compatible File System), and where MySQL is not a HCFS, Hudi cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can tryout options like [Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/) which  is an interface for ETL of data from Hadoop (HDFS, Hive) to SQL tables and viceversa.

If we have a CSV/Textfile Table in Hive, Sqoop can easily export the table from HDFS to MySQL table RDS with commands like below:

```
export --table <mysql_table_name> --export-dir hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/csvdata --connect jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/<db_name> --username <username> --password-file hdfs:///user/test/mysql.password --batch -m 1 --input-null-string "\\N" --input-null-non-string "\\N" --columns <column names to be exported, without whitespace in between the column names
```

Feel free to check out my question post on Sqoop [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107946/how-to-import-parquet-data-from-s3-into-hdfs-using-sqoop)